# Get field type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, typeof

I have class in Typescript. It has some fields

```
field1 : ko.observable<number>();
field2 : ko.observable<string>('');
...
```

In some function in another class I've tried to loop through every object field and for fields of type `number` I need to perform some modifications.

How can I detect this?

---

I've tried next, but always get type as `string` which is logically. `locationModel` filled 
 with values from HTML form, where inputs is of type `text`

```
 Object.keys(locationModel)
 .forEach(property => {
                if (typeof locationModel[property]() === 'number') { }
                else{ }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put automatic type conversion into knockout you can create an extender for that.

In its most basic form it could return a [writable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) that either:

- converts the incoming value on *write* and stores the converted value in the observable, or
- stores the incoming value in the observable unchanged and converts it on *read*.

An implementation of the latter could like this – run the snippet below and note how the type reflects in the viewmodel:

```js
ko.extenders.type = function (target, type) {
    var typedValue = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            var value = target();
            if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null) {
                return value;
            } else {
                return type(value);
            }
        },
        write: target
    });
    typedValue.raw = target;
    return typedValue;
};

var vm = {
    num: ko.observable().extend({type: Number}),
    str: ko.observable().extend({type: String})
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// init some values
vm.num(100);
vm.str(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Num: <input data-bind="value: num"> (raw: <span data-bind="text: num.raw"></span>)<br>
Str: <input data-bind="value: str"> (raw: <span data-bind="text: str.raw"></span>)<br><br>

<hr>
View Model:<br>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that input values from a form is always going to be strings, you have to parse the values properly to make them the type that you want.

So you'll need to manually set up some mapping that allows you to transform all input strings to the appropriate values in your model.

Comment: I agree. I am not sure that one can force observables to be a certain type anyway, that's not how this works. But it's entirely possible to use [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) to make knockout convert values automatically.

Comment: @Tomalak From a typescript-perspective, having observables typed to a specific type is all ok in compile-time, even if those constraints are all lost in runtime, like most of the typing in TS.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe the OP mistakenly thinks TypeScript would involve run-time type conversion?

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, I'm sometimes confuse, so want some unreal things from Typescript...